# cant figure out how to change views using an NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, view, switch-statement, nstimer

I made a class called view2 which is a UIView Controller subclass and when i run the program the timer works fine but when it changes screens it just goes to black and not the picture I have on view2. This is the code I have on the .m of the opening view can anyone see where this is going wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    randomMain = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(2) target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}


-(void)onTimer{

    view2 *second= [[view2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the name of the xib file you want to load (without extension):

```
view2 *second = [[view2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView2Xib" bundle:nil];
```

Or if you create the GUI programmatically, just use a simple `init`:

```
view2 *second = [[view2 alloc] init];
```

Some additional remarks:

- Class names should always start with a capital letter, to distinguish them from variables.
- It's a good idea to include part of the superclass' name in your subclass' name. If I saw a class called `View2`, I would assume it's a `UIView` subclass. I'd rather call it `ViewController2`.
- There is no need to put the interval in parenthesis.
- The action of an `NSTimer` should have a single argument (itself).

**EDIT:**

With a storyboard you have to manually perform the seque you set up between the 2 views:

```
- (void)onTimer {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response I made the view in storyboard and attached the view2 class to it do I need to make a xib for it to get it to work? 
 view2 *second= [[view2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"view2" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil]; This is what I just tried and was not successful.

Comment: You should have mentioned, that you're using a storyboard. See my updated answer.

Comment: You can pass `nil` for the nib name if you have a nib whose name is the name of the class (so, using the name from the question, view2.xib). UIViewController will put two and two together and load the correct nib. If you name the nib something else, then you will have to tell it that name; if you don't create a nib at all for this VC, then you will have to supply its view yourself.

Comment: Thank you guys I finally got it to work I wasnt able to choose a class for the nib and finally realized it was made within a class already and didn't need to assign it. I felt really dumb but oh well. Im just gonna not mess with storyboard for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I would think viewDidLoad is not the appropriate place for your purposes. You should instead use viewDidAppear.

All of DrummerB's remarks are very valid and quite important.